# automatic filling series in cell when a different cell is edited

Tags: excel

I want to add a sequential number in column 1 (so A1, B1, c1, would be 1,2,3) WHEN I enter any data in Column 2. So if a cell doesn't have a value, nothing is entered in the other cell.

The end result should look like this.

```
A- 1    32
B- 2    18
C- 3    16

E- 5     20
```

It's for a box count and config.

I've tried a few things and I am missing a value. Can any one help please?

Comment: were you looking for a VBA solution for this?

Comment: Hi P.campbell,

A vBA answer would help.

I would look at anything right now. Its making me start to tic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help, just in the A1 cell use this formula:

Excel 2007

```
=IF(LEN(B1)>0;ROW(A1);"")
```

Excel 2010

`=IF(LEN(B1)>0,ROW(A1),"")`

And then fill down the cells with the formula. This will write the cell row when it finds anything and a zero when it doesnt:

```
1   test
2   test
3   test
0   
5   test
0   
7   test
```

Comment: If you change your formula to `=IF(LENGTH(B1)>0;ROW(A1);"")` (note the empty string/double quotes) it'll be empty if there isn't anything in B1.

Comment: Corrected, Thanks mskfisher! :)

Comment: Well I guess you have an english version of excel, dont you? Here a screenshot of my excel executing the formula correctly (it's the 2007 one though): http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/2986/20100807005149.png Where "SI" means "IF", "LARGO" means "LENGTH" and "FILA" means "ROW" because I have the spanish version

Comment: @oli206: got it working now. The formula that worked for me is this: =IF(LEN(B1)>0,ROW(A1),"")

Comment: ops, i was making a guess when I said "length", i didnt remember that in the english version is just "len" thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
=IF(LEN(B1)>0,ROW(A1),"") works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this problem would be to leverage the `Worksheet_Change` event. This way you do not need to have any formulas in your spreadsheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        End
    End If

    Target.Offset(0, -1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A")) + 1

End Sub
```

---

To implement this code:

1. In your workbook press `ALT + F11` (this opens VBA editor)
2. Open the **Project Explorer** `(CTRL + R)`
3. Double-clik the sheet that you want the code to apply to e.g. Sheet1
4. In the left-hand dropdown menu select **Worksheet** and in the right hand menu select **Change**
5. Cut and paste the code provided

Hope this helps.